# accessing route prefix in app/providers

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.4

i have a multi template website , i've created multiple folder for differetn templates in my views folder  ... but i have 1 admin template and i want to load admin section from that folder for all

in my route i have something like

```
Route::group(['namespace' => 'Cp', 'prefix' => 'cp'  , 'middleware'=>['admin' ,'auth'] ], function()
{

    Route::get('/' ,  'IndexController@index' )->name('index_cp');
});
```

in `app/providers/ViewServiceProvider.php` im changing template folder dynamically based on database stored value , but im trying to get the prefix of current route so if its `cp` it ignores the template folder and loads template from `cp` folder

```
    public function registerViewFinder()
    {
        $request = app(\Illuminate\Http\Request::class);
        dump($request->route()->getPrefix());
        if($request->route()->getPrefix() != 'cp')
        {
         // read from db &  set the template folder 
        }

    }
```

im getting this error

```
Call to a member function getPrefix() on null
```

basically `$request->route()`  returns null

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think rather than going for the `getPrefix` way you could use the `is()` method on the request object,

where the is method does the following

> The is method allows you to verify that the incoming request URI
>   matches a given pattern. You may use the * character as a wildcard
>   when utilizing this method:

```
if (request()->is('cp/*')) {
   // do the template switching.
}
```

[doc link](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/requests)

Comment: thanx  this `app(\Illuminate\Http\Request::class)->is('cp/*')` worked